# PCRE ignoring matches in c++

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I'm trying to work with C++ and PCRE regular expressions in Ubuntu. I installed almost every piece of software related (libpcrepp and similar), but I can't even match the simplest expression. My code, simplified:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pcrecpp.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   std::string text, a, b;

   text = "Flowers in the forest are darker than in the prairie";

   pcrecpp::RE re("forest");

   if( re.PartialMatch(text, &a, &b) ) {
      std::cout << "match: " << a << b << "\n";
   }

}
```

No errors compiling:

```
g++ t2.cpp -lpcrecpp -o t2
```

And no results when executing. Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> re.PartialMatch(text, &a, &b)

can only return true if there are at least two captures in the regular expression, one for each of the return arguments. Since there are no captures in your regular expression ("forest"), re.PartialMatch is guaranteed to return false, regardless of whether the pattern matches the text.

Comment: I removed the &b leaving the expression:

  re.PartialMatch(text, &a) 

But it is still not working. Thank you, @rici.

Comment: You don't have one capture group, either. Have you read any documentation about regular expressions? A capture group is a part of the regular expression surrounded by `(` and `)` whose match is "captured" and then returned. Since you don't have any of those, all you can do is find out if the match worked (boolean return result). If you use DoMatch, you can also get the length of the match. (see pcrecpp.h for details).

Comment: The expression surrounded by ( ) did the trick. Thanks for your help, @rici.